# What happens when 2 threads write to same object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi there
i am wondering what happens, if 2 threads writes to an object at the same time?
Not sure if this should be threads, i have multiple copies of a view, each copy access and writes to a nsuserdefault object.
What happens if two or more copies of the view writes to the same object? is there some kind of locking mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: thanks joe blow, if nsuserdefaults are thread safe, that would save a lot of trouble for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NSUserDefaults` class is thread-safe, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). So yes, there is probably some kind of locking mechanism inside.

Answer (score 4):

1. If 2 threads write to the same object or structure without some kind of locking primitive, then very bad things will happen.  At best, you'll end up with inconsistent state.  At worst, your app will crash.  NSUserDefaults is defined to be thread safe, so -- yes -- it is using locking of some kind.
2. If you have views running in different threads all writing to the same object, that is indicative of a whole different problem.   The UIKit isn't completely thread safe.  Most UI interaction *must* be done from the main thread.

The docs have a [bunch of information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1) on this.

Comment: That's a lot of information bbum, i will go through the documentation link you gave me. I think i understand what you meant, more reading for me to do :)